# Algorithm for quantity selection

Tags: android, algorithm, android-activity, shopping-cart

I'm stuck with a specific problem that i want to solve.The scenario is like this for **e-cart application on android**

In the app the user get to **choose different quantity** .But the problem is that i have each item with **different quantity measures** and **different stepping function** to increase the quantity.

So how can i Simplify this.

> Can any one suggest me a good algorithm to solve such problem or may
>   be an independent solution

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you mean by "different quantity measures"?

Comment: kg, grams , bunch, piece,etc

Comment: The algorithm is called plus and minus. I think what you are really locking for is a nice data structure.

Comment: Yeah @IngoSchwarz that is what i'm looking for..

Comment: Are you satisfied with the already given answer or should I do a proposal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `Product` class. Each product object has different quantity measures and increment methods. Something like this:

```
public abstract class Product {
    String quantityMeasure; //You can encapsulate this with a getter
    public abstract int step (int value); //here you want to increment "value" with different algorithms.
}
```

Now you can create different product subclasses like this:

```
public class FruitProduct extends Product {
    public abstract int step (int value) {
        //implementation here
    }

    public FruitProduct () {
        quantityMeasure = "grams";
    }
}
```

Now you can get the quantity measure using the `Product` objects.

EDIT:

You can also make the `Product` type an interface like this:

```
public interface Product {
    int step(int value);
    String getQuantityMeasure();
}
```

Remember to implement the `getQuantityMeasure` method as well!

```
public String getQuantityMeasure() {
    return "grams";
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer .This is well and good option but in my case type of product is not fixed and that makes it another problem..

Comment: Then make product an interface instead.

Comment: @omkomawar see my edited answer. I explained how to use an interface as cYrixmorten had suggested.